# Combine two dataframes based on column similarity

Tags: python

I have two data frames, A and B, that I would like to combine based on the similarity of column values.

Specifically, data frame A contains a column called Path that contains path in the following format:
path/module/bla1/fileJava.java

While data frame B contains a column called Class that contains path in the following format:
path.bla2.bla.bla1.fileJava

The two paths do not match perfectly, but I would need to combine the information in row N of data frame B to row M of data frame A when the values of columns A['Path'] and B['Class'] are as similar as possible.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you change the dots in B to '/' (perhaps stored in a new column)? E.g., with `B['Class'].str.replace('.', '/')`?

Comment: of course, but even replacing the dots with "/", the paths would still be similar, but not the equals

Comment: But then your examples of "path/path/path" versus "path.path.path" are not useful: these are exactly the same, except for the (replaceable) slashes versus dots. You should give better examples and a clearer definition of similarity here.

Comment: E.g.,  is "some/module/path" similar to "SOME/MODULE/PATH" or (more) similar to "some/module/pat" (missing 'h')? Or even "somemodule/path"? When should it match, and how many matches for single row N are allowed?

Comment: I agree with you, and for this reason, I edited my question. Thank you

Comment: How many rows are allowed to match? What if there is also a Class item "path.bla3.bla.bla1.fileJava"? That seems to match equally well to the example Path as the example Class.

Comment: I've upper/lowercased some words, to try and avoid confusing between column names and the generic name "path".